# How to solve duplicate date values in Time Series Analysis?

Tags: pandas, statistics, time-series, statsmodels, kaggle

I have a dataframe with multiple Date values

[image]

for my Time Series Analysis. I suppose they took the values at different times of the day, and just wrote it as the date.

So, I am thinking of generating random times for the values, like the first 9/9/2016 value would be at 9pm, the second at 3pm, the third at 9am, the fourth at 3am (Since the data is getting older and older).

What is the best practice?

Comment: All dates have 4 occurrences or it's variable (like '9/7/2016')?

Comment: All dates have 4 occurences. Every single one of them. So I'm thinking that they measured it in fairly regular sequences

Comment: The best practice probably depends a bit on the details of the data collection process. If it's realistic to assume that the data have been collected at regular intervals (also during the night at 3am), then the equally spaced time grid seems a good solution. If, say, the data are collected four times a day at a weather station whenever measurement conditions are good, then measurements times can differ across days and it would probably be best to average the observations for each each day. The resulting data series would be at the daily frequency. There are probably more scenarios...

Comment: What would you say is the most realistic for haze levels? 
The time series analysis is stationary, and I do believe that the haze levels would be measured in regular intervals, 6 hours apart. The one thing I'm scared is that if I take the average, would it look more like a line graph than a time series graph?

Comment: @wel Does your data source provide any information on how/when these haze levels were measured? If not, then indeed equidistant 6 hours apart seems most probable. And yes, the "disadvantage" of averaging across all observations within the same day is the loss of all intraday variation (or say high-frequency information). If you are interested in say a forecast of a daily average haze level on a typical day next week, then this might not be a problem. If you are interested at the haze level tomorrow at 3pm, then these intraday variations are of course relevant.

Comment: @HannoReuvers
There is no data explantion. They just said "Date - Date".

Since this is a kaggle competition, i just checked the test.csv file, and it seems that they just want us to predict the levels by date only. So now I'm thinking, maybe average is the way to go? Because if I were to take 4 different values for everyday, what value would I ultimately submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way (or it is highly unlikely) that actual good data would have values like this. You mentioned that this is from a Kaggle competition - I doubt they would leave these kind of things to any ambiguity.

What I'm thinking is that you didn't read the dataset carefully. Maybe it's the same date but for different variables? For example, maybe they measured your values on the same date, but in different areas?

You may want to check your other columns before jumping to conclusions.

Comment: The competition deadline is over now, and I haven't been back to revise this question, but you are spot on. It's actually pretty impressive how correct you are. The different variables in this case was the different gases measured.